# OpenAI GPT-3 API: Why do I get only partial completion? Why is the completion cut off?

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-3

I tried the following code but got only partial results like

```
[{"light_id": 0, "color
```

I was expecting the full JSON as suggested on this page:

https://medium.com/@richardhayes777/using-chatgpt-to-control-hue-lights-37729959d94f

```
import json
import os
import time
from json import JSONDecodeError
from typing import List

import openai
openai.api_key =  "xxx"

HEADER = """
I have a hue scale from 0 to 65535. 
red is 0.0
orange is 7281
yellow is 14563
purple is 50971
pink is 54612
green is 23665
blue is 43690

Saturation is from 0 to 254
Brightness is from 0 to 254

Two JSONs should be returned in a list. Each JSON should contain a color and a light_id. 
The light ids are 0 and 1. 
The color relates a key "color" to a dictionary with the keys "hue", "saturation" and "brightness". 

Give me a list of JSONs to configure the lights in response to the instructions below. 
Give only the JSON and no additional characters. 
Do not attempt to complete the instruction that I give.
Only give one JSON for each light. 
"""

completion = openai.Completion.create(model="text-davinci-003", prompt=HEADER)
print(completion.choices[0].text)
```

Comment: add the max_tokens parameter to the `Completion.create` call. If you don't, it defaults to 16. https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create#completions/create-max_tokens

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### In general

#### GPT-3 API (i.e., [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api))

If you get partial completion (i.e., if the completion is cut off), it's because **the `max_tokens` parameter is set too low or you didn't set it at all** (in this case, it defaults to [`16`](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create#completions/create-max_tokens)). You need to set it higher, **but the token count of your prompt and completion together cannot exceed the model's context length**.

See the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create#completions/create-max_tokens):

[image: Screenshot 1]

#### GPT-3.5 and GPT-4 API (i.e., [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api))

Compared to the GPT-3 API, the GPT-3.5 and GPT-4 APIs have the `max_tokens` parameter set to [`infinite`](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create#chat/create-max_tokens) by default.

[image: Screenshot 2]

### Your case

You're using `text-davinci-003` (i.e., the GPT-3 API). If you don't set `max_tokens = 1024` the completion you get will be cut off. Take a careful look at the [tutorial](https://medium.com/@richardhayes777/using-chatgpt-to-control-hue-lights-37729959d94f) you're referring to once again.

If you run `test.py`, the OpenAI API will return a completion:

> Light 0 should be red:  [{"light_id": 0, "color": {"hue": 0,
> "saturation": 254, "brightness": 254}},{"light_id": 1, "color": }]
>
> Light 1 should be orange: [{"light_id": 0, "color": {"hue": 0,
> "saturation": 254, "brightness": 254}},{"light_id": 1, "color":
> {"hue": 7281, "saturation": 254, "brightness": 254}}]

**test.py**

```
import openai
import os

openai.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

HEADER = """
I have a hue scale from 0 to 65535. 
red is 0.0
orange is 7281
yellow is 14563
purple is 50971
pink is 54612
green is 23665
blue is 43690

Saturation is from 0 to 254
Brightness is from 0 to 254

Two JSONs should be returned in a list. Each JSON should contain a color and a light_id. 
The light ids are 0 and 1. 
The color relates a key "color" to a dictionary with the keys "hue", "saturation" and "brightness". 

Give me a list of JSONs to configure the lights in response to the instructions below. 
Give only the JSON and no additional characters. 
Do not attempt to complete the instruction that I give.
Only give one JSON for each light. 
"""

completion = openai.Completion.create(model="text-davinci-003", prompt=HEADER, max_tokens=1024)
print(completion.choices[0].text)
```

Answer (score -4):

```
import openai 

openai.organization = "******"    
openai.api_key = "******"    
openai.Model.list()
   
completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(    
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",   
  messages=[    
    {"role": "user", "content": "hi"}    
  ]   
)
   
print(completion.choices[0].message)
response = completion.choices[0].text
print(response)
```

Comment: Could you explain the answer, please?