# ApiChatGPT Cutting Text

Tags: javascript, node.js, chatgpt-api

The chatGPT API is clipping the response text. Is there a way to resolve this? If there is no way to solve it, how can I remove the paragraph that had the text cut off. Can someone help me?

```js
// API_URL = https://api.openai.com/v1/completions

async function newUserMessage(newMessage) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(API_URL, {
      prompt: newMessage,
      model: 'text-davinci-003',
      max_tokens: 150
     }, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
      },
    });
    
    const { text } = response.data.choices[0];
    const newText = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
    setResponse(newText);
    setQuery("");
   } catch (error) {
     console.error(error);
   }
 };
```

Comment: How long is `newMessage`?

Comment: @0stone0 yes. Does the API have any limitations regarding text size?

Comment: Yes it does, since you're passing `max_token` to, the prompt will be cut of if the limit is reached/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI GPT-3 API: Why do I get only partial completion? Why is the completion cut off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75648132/openai-gpt-3-api-why-do-i-get-only-partial-completion-why-is-the-completion-cu)

Comment: @RokBenko Thank you very much for the comment :), but I already managed to clear my doubts. I'll leave the link here: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAI language model processes text by dividing it into tokens. The API response was getting clipped because the text sent was going over the 100 token limit. To avoid this problem, I set the max_tokens property to its maximum value.

This was my solution:

```
const settings = {
  prompt: newMessage,
  model: 'text-davinci-003',
  temperature: 0.5,
  max_tokens: 2048,
  frequency_penalty: 0.5,
  presence_penalty: 0,
 }
```

Here is the documentation I used: **platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create**