# OpenAI converting API code from GPT-3 to chatGPT-3.5

Tags: php, openai-api, gpt-3, chatgpt-api

Below is my working code for the GPT-3 API. I am having trouble converting it to work with chatGPT-3.5.

```
<?php include('../config/config.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Chatbot</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container py-5">
  <h1 class="mb-5 text-center">
    <div class="logo"> <img src="/images/Logo-PocketAI.svg" height="80" width="210" aria-label="PocketAI.Online Logo" title="PocketAI.Online Logo" alt="SPocketAI.Online Logo" class="img-fluid"> </div>
  </h1>
  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
    <select class="form-select" id="tab-select" aria-label="Select your purpose">
      <option value="exam" selected>Exam</option>
      <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
    </select>
    <label for="tab-select">Select your purpose:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
      <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your question or comment here" id="prompt"></textarea>
      <label for="prompt">Enter your question or comment here</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-append username w-100 mt-3 mb-4">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100" type="button" id="send-button">Send</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="output" class="mb-3" style="height: 300px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid lightgray; padding: 10px;"></div>
  <div id="exam-instructions" class="mb-3" style="display: block;">
    <h3>Exam</h3>
    <p>PocketAI can create multiple choice and true false questions in a format that enables import into Brightspace D2L quizzes using Respondus. Place PocketAI output into a Word document before importing with Respondus. Ask PocketAI questions like the following: <br>
      <br>
      Create 3 multiple choice questions about carbohydrates for a freshman Nutrition online college course.<br>
      Create 2 true false questions about business for a sophomore Business face to face college course.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="feedback-instructions" class="mb-3" style="display: none;">
    <h3>Feedback</h3>
    <p>Enter text to receive writing feedback.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
const previousPrompts = [];
const userName = "<strong>User</strong>";
const chatbotName = "<strong>PocketAI</strong>";

const selectDropdown = document.getElementById("tab-select");

selectDropdown.addEventListener("change", function() {
  const activeTabId = this.value;
  
  // hide all instruction sections
  document.querySelectorAll("[id$='-instructions']").forEach(function(instructionSection) {
    instructionSection.style.display = "none";
  });
  
  // show the instruction section for the active tab
  document.getElementById(`${activeTabId}-instructions`).style.display = "block";
});

document.getElementById("send-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const prompt = document.getElementById("prompt").value;
  const activeTabId = selectDropdown.value;

  const endpoint = "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions";
  const apiKey = "<?=$OPEN_AI_KEY;?>";

  document.getElementById("send-button").innerHTML = '<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span> Sending...';

  let promptText = "";
  
  switch (activeTabId) {
    case "exam":
        promptText = "Create quiz questions in the following format: Begin each question with a number followed by a period, and then include the question wording. For each question, include four answer choices listed as letters (A, B, C, D) followed by a period and at least one space before the answer wording. Designate the correct answer by placing an asterisk (*) directly in front of the answer letter (do not put a space between the asterisk and the answer choice). Place the asterisk in front of the answer letter, only the front. It is important that correct answers are identified. Don't make up answers, only select factual answers. For example formatting (don't use this specific example), \"1. What is the recommended daily intake of dietary fiber? A. 10 grams B. 25 grams *C. 50 grams D. 75 grams\". Format true false questions the same way. If you are unsure of the correct answer, don't create the question. Every quiz question and answer must be 100% correct and factual. Do not make up answers. All answers must be correct.";
      break;
     case "feedback":
      promptText = "Can you provide feedback on the writing, grammar, sentence structure, punctuation, and style of this student's paper? The paper should be analyzed for its strengths and weaknesses in terms of written communication. Please provide suggestions for improvement and examples to help the student understand how to make the writing better. The feedback should be specific and provide actionable steps that the student can take to improve their writing skills. Please include at least three examples of areas that could be improved and specific suggestions for how to improve them, such as correcting grammar errors, restructuring sentences, or improving the use of punctuation.";
      break;
  }
  
  const requestData = {
    prompt: previousPrompts.join("\n") + promptText + "\n" + prompt,
    max_tokens: 400,
      model: "text-davinci-003",
    n: 1,
    stop: "",
    temperature: 0.5,
      top_p: 0.0,
      frequency_penalty: 0.0,
      presence_penalty: 0
  };
        
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestData),
  };
  
  fetch(endpoint, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const reply = data.choices[0].text;
      
      // Add the user message to the chat history
      const userMessage = `<div class="message-container">
        <div class="username">${userName}:&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="user-message">${prompt}</div>
      </div>`;
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += userMessage;
      
      const chatbotMessage = `<div class="message-container">
  <div class="username">${chatbotName}:&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="chatbot-message" style="white-space: pre-wrap">${reply}<i class="bi bi-clipboard-check copy-button" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Copy to clipboard" data-text="${reply}" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></div>
</div>`; 
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += chatbotMessage;

// Add an event listener to each "Copy to Clipboard" button
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("copy-button")) {
    const textToCopy = event.target.dataset.text;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(textToCopy);
  }
});
     // Scroll to the bottom of the chat history
      document.getElementById("output").scrollTop = document.getElementById("output").scrollHeight;
    
      // Clear the user input field
      document.getElementById("prompt").value = "";
    
      previousPrompts.push(prompt);
      // Clear the spinner and show the "Send" button again
      document.getElementById("send-button").innerHTML = 'Send';
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    
      // Hide the spinner and show the "Send" button again
      document.getElementById("send-button").innerHTML = 'Send';
    });
});

document.getElementById("prompt").addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("send-button").
click();
  }
});
</script>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have read https://openai.com/blog/introducing-chatgpt-and-whisper-apis and referred to this - [OpenAI ChatGPT (gpt-3.5-turbo) API: How to access the message content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75613656/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-turbo-api-how-to-access-the-message-content) but still can't make it work.

I've tried changing the requestData to this, but no luck:

```
const requestData = {
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages: [
      { role: "user", content: prompt }
    ],
    max_tokens: 400,
    temperature: 0.5,
    top_p: 1,
    frequency_penalty: 0,
    presence_penalty: 0
  };
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's the error that you received? turbo API response content can be retrieved by `response.data.choices[0].message.content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better check your `requestData` object, the GPT 3.5 turbo doesn't need these props

> max_tokens,temperature,top_p: 1,frequency_penalty,presence_penalty

I made the same mistake too, GPT 3.5 turbo is wayyyyy easier to use than I expected. Here's OpenAI sample:

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages: [{role: "user", content: "Hello world"}],
});
console.log(completion.data.choices[0].message);
```