# Get content output from OpenAI library

Tags: openai-api

I prepare integration openAI API with Codeigniter 4, for this I use library:

```
https://github.com/orhanerday/open-ai
```

I write controller CI4:

```php
public function openAIPost()
  {
    $response = array();
    if ($this->request->getMethod() === 'post'){
    question = $this->request->getPost('question');
    $open_ai_key = getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY');
    $open_ai = new OpenAi($open_ai_key);
    $complete = $open_ai->chat([
      'model' => 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      'messages' => [
         [
           "role" => "user",
           "content" => $question
         ]
       ],
       'temperature' => 1.0,
       'max_tokens' => 10,
       'frequency_penalty' => 0,
       'presence_penalty' => 0,
    ]);
    $response['complete'] = $complete;
   }
  echo json_encode($response);
}
```

But I get in output:

```json
    {
        "id": "chatcmpl-6xxhQ2FLm08VhE8KKHsTpilkvpMTS",
        "object": "chat.completion",
        "created": 1679748856,
        "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301",
        "usage": {
            "prompt_tokens": 9,
            "completion_tokens": 10,
            "total_tokens": 19
        },
        "choices": [{
            "message": {
                "role": "assistant",
                "content": "This is a test of the AI language model."
            },
            "finish_reason": "length",
            "index": 0
        }]
    }
```

How to get only content from response?

Comment: I read all this related questions but I not see  in this questions correct answear which can help me resolve this output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API: How do I access the message content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75613656/openai-chatgpt-gpt-3-5-api-how-do-i-access-the-message-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should all you need in the JSON response returned by the OpenAI API you have.

You should navigate the JSON object and extract the message content using the following line.

`$content = $complete.choices[0].message.content`

it should give you `"This is a test of the AI language model."`